# Find admin group name

Tags: powershell, admin, local

I need to find the name of the admin group local on a windows computer with powershell. For example, if the language is french, it is "Administrateurs" but if it's english, it's "Administrators".

I find this vbs code who could solve my problem.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colAccounts = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Group Where LocalAccount = TRUE And SID = 'S-1-5-32-544'")

For Each objAccount in colAccounts
    Wscript.Echo objAccount.Name
Next
```

I'm starting with powershell so could someone "translate" this in powershell ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
gwmi win32_group -filter "LocalAccount = $TRUE And SID = 'S-1-5-32-544'" | select -expand name
```

Comment: One last question, I need to do this for a batch too... Do you have an Idea how to do it ? Thank's

Comment: @user1965878 call you vbs script from the .bat file.

Comment: The problem is this batch will be used with the SSCM (System Center Configuration Manager) and we have some problems with scripts other than batch. That's why I hope we can do it with batch.